# Solutions of the functional inequality $f(x)\geq f(y)(1+x-y)$

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

Consider the functional inequalities:

$$
(1)\; f(x)\geq f(y)(1+x-y) \; ; \; x,y\in \mathbb{R},
$$
$$
(2)\; \frac{f(x)}{f(y)}\geq 1+x-y \; ; \; x,y\in \mathbb{R}.
$$

It is obvious that all functions of the form $f(t)=ce^t$ with $c\geq 0$ (resp. $c\neq 0$) satisfy
$(1)$ (resp. $(2)$).

**Are there any other solutions** for them?

Thnaks in advance

Comment: Any positive function that satisfies $f'(x)\ge f(x)$ is a candidate.

Answer (score 3):

We deal with (2). For any given $t,\delta\in\mathbb R$, we have
$$\frac{f(t+n\delta)}{f(t)}=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{f(t+(i+1)\delta)}{f(t+i\delta)}\geq (1+\delta)^n,$$
so
$$\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}\geq \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x-y}{n}\right)^n=e^{x-y}.$$
Furthermore, as $e^v\geq 1+v$ for all real $v$, this is sufficient for (2). However,
$$\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}\geq e^{y-x};$$
these two inequalities multiply to $1\geq 1$ (and we can multiply them since everything is positive), and so equality must hold; as a result, $f(x)=ce^x$ for some constant $c$.

For (1), the process is very similar, and the answer is only slightly different, in essentially the way that the solutions you found differ (values of $0$ are acceptable; negative values are not).

Comment: I'd like to see a discontinuous solution. A solution of (1) is certainly convex in $\mathbb{R}$, and thus continuous and differentiable, except at a countable set of arguments.

Comment: @ -Carl Schildkraut. I think every solution of (1) is differentiable and so the only solutions are $ce^t$ with $c\geq 0$.

Comment: @ -Carl Schildkraut & Prof. Vector. Many thanks for your answer and comment. Do you know some references (paper, book, website, etc.) for such functional inequalities?

Comment: @- Prof. Vector. Why it is convex?

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand $\displaystyle f(x)=\sup_y [f(y)+f(y)(x-y)]$ is the supremum of a set of affine-linear functions, and thus convex.

Comment: Sorry about that -- you're correct. I assumed that $x>y$ in an inequality I derived, when in fact this doesn't need to be true.